# Tags [stats] and [statistics]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We have these tags:

- [stats](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stats)
- [statistics](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics)

(No question uses both.)

Do we need both of these tags?

Is there a difference? (Not sure if it makes sense, because I have no experience in this domain, but maybe one for [statistical software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_statistical_packages) and one for software that "gathers" stat(istic)s?)

Comment: I'm in favor of merging [stats] -> [statistics], if no one can find a reason not to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since we seem to have consensus, merged [stats](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stats) -> [statistics](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics).

Answer (score 4):

I think the tags are used for two different things: gathering statistics from observed phenomena, and analyzing statistical data. However the split between the two tag names [stats](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stats) and [statistics](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics) is not correlated with these two meanings. I can't see any difference between the tags, so they should be merged.

Let's make [statistics](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics) the main tag, since it's the unabbreviated name (and it's the one almost all SE sites use).